# How and where to apply multiple filter in MVVM pattern using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, filtering

Good day, masters of MVVM and Entity Framework guru!
I'm writing a MVVM-based application using SimpleMVVM scaffolding and EF. 
It is supposed to be able to filter list in a DataGrid, based on multiple parameter from several ComboBox. So there could be no filtering at all (no options in the comboboxes are chosen) or multiple filter could be enabled.

I want to approach it simply. 
Hence I wrote serviceAgent (offered by SimpleMVVM framework), which implements

```
List<event> ListAllEventsOf(int level, int partner, int place, int sport, int participant);
```

function.
All of its parameters are all possible filters Events-list could have. So this function is going to check each parameter whether it have valid value. if so, the function will apply where-based select.

That is the plan of mine, but I feel that there something wrong about it. What is the common approach to multifiltering in MVVM and EF?

Comment: I am not sure how do you bind your data to the grid. If this is WPF,  you already have your grid filled and you just want to filter the existing data, you don't need to go and filter your data source but just the CollectionView that WPF automatically associates with it, which is meant exactly for that. You can access that collection view with `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(<YourDataSourceCollectionHere>)` 

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx)

Comment: @Kyopaxa, you are absolutely right! but I wanted to implement Database-side filter due to my database works on remoted server